# DataBase (datamodel) to build a folder structure

Tags: java, algorithm, directory

Planning on building a Folder based structure in Java.

I will be using a jquery plugin for the GUI, so I don't need need information on how to display the folder structure.

I am looking for the backend logic on how folder information is stored, such that it can be retrieved in a quick and efficient manner.

Each folder will have multiple subfolders.
From a leaf folder, we should be able access the root quickly and efficiently

Example:

```
+Folder1
  |__SubFolder1_1
  |__SubFolder1_2
        |_SubSubFolder1_2_1
        |_
+Folder2
  |__SubFolder2_1
        |_SubFolder2_1_1
        |_SubFolder2_1_2
             |_SubFolder2_1_2_1
```

New folders could be added randomly.
Folder can be renamed.
Folders can be deleted.

**My Question is:**

How would these folder details be stored in the database?

Again, I am looking for a fast and efficient means of storing and retrieving this information.

Comment: What do you mean, from a leaf, access the root quickly? *The* root, or that folder's containing folder? In any case, seems like a normal parent_id mechanism would work, but without knowing what kinds of operations you're doing, it's hard to say how to be efficient at it.

Comment: And how fast do you think it needs to be? Since you mention jQuery, it sounds like a web app. Network speed will dwarf DB lookup based on an indexed ID.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For storing in DB, the easiest and most straight forward way is to have an parent_folder_id for each folder/node. This should be good enough in most scenario, especially you are going to construct the folder object structure and do manipulation base on the object model.

Depends on your requirement, there is a quite common case that you need to

1. Find out all subfolders under certain folder
2. Perform the lookup directly from DB, by SQL.

If it is what you are looking for, then there is a interesting method that you may have a look:
Each DB record will have 2 extra number field, let's call it LEFT and RIGHT

assume a tree like this:

```
ROOT
  + A
  | + A1
  | + A2
  + B
    + B1
```

What is going to be stored in DB is

```
Node  LEFT  RIGHT  ... other fields
ROOT   1    12
A      2    7
A1     3    4
A2     5    6
B      8    11
B1     9    10
```

- each parent node is having LEFT = first child's LEFT - 1, and RIGHT = last child's RIGHT + 1
- leaf node will have LEFT and RIGHT being 2 consecutive number
- each node's LEFT should be = prior sibling's RIGHT + 1, RIGHT = next sibling's LEFT - 1

When you need to find all nodes under certain node (N) by SQL, simply find out all nodes with LEFT > N.LEFT and RIGHT < N.RIGHT

You can easily perform insert/delete by bulk updating related nodes by (not a difficult task, leave it to you  :P )

This is probably not very OO friendly but in case the requirement I mentioned is what you need, u may consider using this method.

Comment: so if we add a subfolder in A1, then all the Node after, A2, B, B1 will need to update their Left and right ? Is that expensive?

Comment: It highly depends on your use.  If there are hundred million records, then ya it could be expensive.  If we are talking  in magnitude of thousands, it should be quite cheap for almost all DBMS for such single SQL update, with proper indices.  Anyway, there is no single solution that fit all scenarios.

Answer (score 11):

This is good question, but without a lot of specifics, it is hard to talk about the 'best' solution.

You can map this to the abstract question of how to store an n-ary tree in a relational database.

Here are some of the variables that affect the problem:

1. What is the total size of the directory structure?
2. How many separate VMs perform writes to the structure?
3. Are move operations frequent?
4. Is faulting an entire subtree an important operation too?
5. Does your database support tree walks, or do you need a solution that works with any reasonable relational database?

The following assumes your database doesn't have special provisions for performing tree walks.

There are two pure persistence models for n-ary trees.

The first is to simply write each node with a parent reference:

```
| NodeId | ParentId | Name       | ....
|--------|----------|------------|-----
```

This approach simplifies the move of a folder, but deletes, queries for all nested subfolders and finding root become expensive.

The second pure model is to persist every ancestral relationship separate from the folder details

```
| NodeId | Name     | ....
|--------|----------|------
...


| NodeId | AncestorId | Distance | 
|--------|------------|----------|
...
```

Here, the folder /food/dairy/cheese/cheddar would produce

```
| NodeId | Name     |
|--------|----------|
| #0     | (root)   |
| #1     | food     |
| #2     | dairy    |
| #3     | cheese   |
| #4     | cheddar  |


| NodeId | AncestorId | Distance |
|--------|------------|----------|
| #1     | #0         | 1        |
| #2     | #0         | 2        |
| #2     | #1         | 1        |
| #3     | #0         | 3        |
| #3     | #1         | 2        |
| #3     | #2         | 1        |
| #4     | #0         | 4        |
| #4     | #1         | 3        |
| #4     | #2         | 2        |
| #4     | #3         | 1        |
```

This approach is very expensive for moves, and a new directory causes `d` inserts, where `d` is the distance from the root. But a subtree listing is a single query. The ancestry path is also a single query; an `order by Distance desc` will let you get to the root and first folder quickly.

But narrowly reading your question, a variant of the first approach, simply adding root as well might be the right approach for you:

```
| NodeId | ParentId | RootId | Name       | ....
|--------|----------|--------|------------|-----
```

Note that moving a folder will be expensive, because you need to determine all nested subfolders, and update all those records' RootId.

Comment: Thank you, I will be using a combination of your answer and answer provided by @AdrianShum. Since I will be using more of Adrian's answer I will mark him as the right answer

Answer (score 0):

Linked List, which is documented in the Java API here:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

As a general Computer Science structure, read this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list

I hope it helps

Comment: Actually more of a tree, like "directory tree".

Comment: @DaveNewton Thank You, But I am looking for information on how to store the information in the database (data model) so that I can store/retrieve data quickly.

Comment: @kensenjohn Right, and "quickly" depends on how/what you're trying to retrieve.

Answer (score 0):

For the database, keep it simple. A table named folder - the only columns would be Id, Name, ParentId. Now every folder will have a parent, and some folders will have children. To load children:

```
SELECT * FROM Folder WHERE Id == ParentFolderId
```