# Hibernate: How do I join a table with itself?

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I have a problem joining a table. Actually I'm really lost on how to do it. I have this Hibernate table mapping.

```
<class name="Technology" table="TECHNOLOGIES">
    <id name="technoId">
        <column name="techno_id" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>        
    <property name="description" type="java.lang.String">
        <column name="description" />
    </property>
    <many-to-one name="parent" class="Technology" />
</class>
```

The column parent is related with the same table. An example of the table so you can understand me.

techno_id | description | parent

1------------"Java"----------null

2------------"Hibernate"------1

3------------"HQL"------------2

4------------".NET"----------null

5------------"NHibernate"----4

That's basically an example of the table, it doesn't have real data, it's just an example.
What I want to do is, in a method that receives a techno_id, run with Criteria or HQL, and that brings me a List of results with the children id's too. 
For example, if I send to the method the "1" techno_id, it should bring me a List with the ids "1, 2, 3".
I hope I was as clear as possible and you can help me.
Thanks, and sorry for my english jaja.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use join tag with inverse

```
<join table ="Technologies" inverse ="true" optional = "false">
  <key column = "techno_id"/>
  <many-to-one name="parent" class="Technology" />
</join>
```

Comment: Thanks, but how I do the method? I have to make a method that receives a techno_id and look it for all the techno_id's that are children of him, and the children of them too.

Comment: Or how I do the query or the criteria's restrictions?

Comment: Well you have the pojo `Technology` in that you define a `Technology parent` object. Then simple hql eg: "from Technology tech where tech.parent = :techno" where techno could be set to another `Technology` obj

Comment: But what happens when a child have children too? In my example, if I give "1" to the method, it have to bring me the ids (1, 2, 3) beeing 3 a son of 2, and 2 a son of 1. I don't know I said it clear. Thxs!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing it.

1. By Criteria :

   ```
   1. For specific level fetching : e.g 3 level fetching(As per your example)
   public Technology getAllChildrenTechnology(long parentID){
    Crtieria criteria = session.createCriteria(Technology.class);
    criteria.add(Restriction.eq("id",parentID));
    criteria.setFetchMode("parent",FetchMode.JOIN);
    criteria.setFetchMode("parent.parent",FetchMode.JOIN);
    criteria.setResultTransformer(criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_PROPERTY);
    Technology techno = (Technology)criteria.uniqueResult();
    return techno;
   }

   2. For N level Fetching : You need to create n level for loop.(Recursive loop using above).
   ```
2. By Lazy :

   There is a feature in hibernate that allow us to fetch some joins without using criteria.

   ```
   <many-to-one name="parent" class="Technology"  lazy="false"/>
   ```

Comment: But the problem is that, that method brings me only one Technology, what I need is (without knowing how many levels of children i will have) a method that I send it a Techno_id and the method returns me a Collection of Technologies that are children of that Technology, and also bring me all the children of the children, etc.

Comment: In that case , you need to use N Level Fecthing as i have already suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this question is not really Hibernate specific.  Even you are writing SQL, you have no easy way to get a node with all its descendant, without special handling in design.

Easiest way is to have each Technology contains List of child technologies (Bidirectional relationship). Then traverse Technology's children recursively.

If you need quick retrieval from persistence storage, you have to cater that in your design.  One way is as described in an answer I wrote before for a similar question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7524077/395202
This method is not that Hibernate friendly anyway (It still works, just need extra attentions)